# Get files info from directories path on another server (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to get files information like file name, size, created date, etc... from directories on another server. I tried using xp_cmdshell to get files from directories but it only set local directories path,
is there any way to set the server and then the directories path using query on sql server? thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL Server? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: First of all, don't use `xp_cmdshell`. There's a very good reason it's disabled by default. Use a batch or powershell script to retrieve the list of files and write it into the database. *That's* what `xp_cmdshell` has to do too, running under the privileged SQL Server service account

Comment: If you want to list the files in a shared folder on another server just write `dir \\someserver\someshare`...`. In Powershell you could use [Write-SqlTableData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) to write the results to a table